# How to know what the JSON script do, and decode the JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I got some JavaScript code, I want to know what the code do. So, I try to decode it. But there still undecoded code. I don't know what to do? Can anyone tell me how to decode them?

```
    $.showFeature('.featured-section', JSON.parse(theme));
});
//]]>
<
/script><script>
//<![CDATA[document.write(unescape('<script language="javascript">function dF(s){var s1=unescape(s.substr(0,s.length-1)); var t='';for(i=0;i<s1.length;i++)t+=String.fromCharCode(s1.charCodeAt(i)-s.substr(s.length-1,1));document.write(unescape(t));}</script>'));dF('&4DTDSJQU&31MBOHVBHF&4E&33kbwbtdsjqu&33&4F&1B&39gvodujpo&39&35&3:&8C&31&35/ejtqmbzHbmmfsz&4Egvodujpo&39f&3Dt&3:&8Cjg&39&32f&3:sfuvso&322&4Cwbs&31u&4E&8Cjoefy`dpmvnot&4B5&3Djoefy`cfgpsfDmbtt&4B&33dpm.tn.4&33&8E&4Cu&37&37&35/fyufoe&39u&3Dt&3:&3D&35&39f&3:/fbdi&39gvodujpo&39&3:&8Ctxjudi&39qbstfGmpbu&39u/joefy`dpmvnot&3:&3:&8Cdbtf&313&4B&35&39uijt&3:/sfnpwfDmbtt&39u/joefy`cfgpsfDmbtt&3:/beeDmbtt&39&33dpm.tn.7&33&3:&4Ccsfbl&4Cdbtf&314&4B&35&39uijt&3:/sfnpwfDmbtt&39u/joefy`cfgpsfDmbtt&3:/beeDmbtt&39&33dpm.tn.5&33&3:&4Ccsfbl&4Cdbtf&317&4B&35&39uijt&3:/sfnpwfDmbtt&39u/joefy`cfgpsfDmbtt&3:/beeDmbtt&39&33dpm.tn.3&33&3:&8E&8E&3:&4Cwbs&31j&3Ds&4E1&3Do&4E1&3Dp&4Eofx&31Bssbz&4C&35&39f&3:/fbdi&39gvodujpo&39&3:&8Cjg&39j&4E&35&39uijt&3:&3D&35&39uijt&3:/ifjhiu&39&33bvup&33&3:&3DupqQptujpo&4Ej/qptjujpo&39&3:/upq&3Do&32&4EupqQptujpo&3:&8Cgps&39dvssfouEjw&4E1&4CdvssfouEjw&4Dp/mfohui&4CdvssfouEjw,,&3:p&6CdvssfouEjw&6E/ifjhiu&39s&3:&4Cp/mfohui&4E1&3Do&4EupqQptujpo&3Ds&4Ej/ifjhiu&39&3:&3Dp/qvti&39j&3:&8Efmtf&31p/qvti&39j&3:&3Ds&4Es&4Dj/ifjhiu&39&3:&4Gj/ifjhiu&39&3:&4Bs&4Cgps&39dvssfouEjw&4E1&4CdvssfouEjw&4Dp/mfohui&4CdvssfouEjw,,&3:p&6CdvssfouEjw&6E/ifjhiu&39s&3:&8E&3:&8E&4C&31&8E&3:&39kRvfsz&3:&4C&1B&4D0TDSJQU&4F&1B&1:&1:&1:1');var _0xfaa2=["#plug-ins [language="javascript"]","remove"];$(function(){var _0x33e4x1=$(_0xfaa2[0]);if(_0x33e4x1){_0x33e4x1[_0xfaa2[1]]()};});$(function(){var theme = !$('.theme-config').data('config') ? false : 
$('.theme-config').data('config');
theme = JSON.stringify(theme);
$.displayGallery('.simpleCart_shelfItem', JSON.parse(theme));
}); //]]>
<
/script><script>/ /
<
![CDATA[document.write(unescape('<script language="javascript">function dF(s){var s1=unescape(s.substr(0,s.length-1)); var t='
            ';for(i=0;i<s1.length;i++)t+=String.fromCharCode(s1.charCodeAt(i)-s.substr(s.length-1,1));document.write(unescape(t));}</script>')); dF('&4DTDSJQU&31MBOHVBHF&4E&33kbwbtdsjqu&33&4F&1B&39gvodujpo&39&35&3:&8C&31&35/beeDbsuBmfsu&4Egvodujpo&39u&3Db&3:&8Cjg&39&32u&3:sfuvso&322&4Cwbs&31f&4E&8Cdbsu`cuo`mpbejoh&4B&38&4Dj&31dmbtt&4E&33gb&31gb.tqjoofs&31gb.tqjo&33&4F&4D0j&4F&31Beejoh&31up&31dbsu&32&38&3Ddbsu`cuo`tvddftt&4B&38&4Dj&31dmbtt&4E&33gb&31gb.difdl&33&4F&4D0j&4F&31Jufn&31beefe&32&38&3Ddbsu`cuo`fssps&4B&38&4Dj&31dmbtt&4E&33gb&31gb.fydmbnbujpo.usjbohmf&33&4F&4D0j&4F&31Qmfbtf&31tfmfdu&31pqujpo&32&38&8E&4Cf&37&37&35/fyufoe&39f&3Db&3:&3D&35&39u&3:/fbdi&39gvodujpo&39&3:&8C&35&39uijt&3:/buus&39&33ebub.mpbejoh&33&3Df/dbsu`cuo`mpbejoh&3:/buus&39&33ebub.cvuupo&33&3D&35&39u&3:/iunm&39&3:&3:/buus&39&33ebub.tvddftt&33&3Df/dbsu`cuo`tvddftt&3:/buus&39&33ebub.fssps&33&3Df/dbsu`cuo`fssps&3:&8E&3:&3D&35&39u&3:/po&39&33dmjdl&33&3Dgvodujpo&39&3:&8Cwbs&31u&4E&35&39uijt&3:&3Db&4Eu/qbsfout&39&33/tjnqmfDbsu`tifmgJufn&33&3:/gjstu&39&3:&3Df&4Eb/gjoe&39&33/jufn`tj{f&33&3:/wbm&39&3:&3Dj&4Eb/gjoe&39&33/jufn`dpmps&33&3:/wbm&39&3:&4Csfuvso&31f&4Ef&4Gf/upVqqfsDbtf&39&3:&4Bwpje&311&3Dj&4Ej&4Gj/upVqqfsDbtf&39&3:&4Bwpje&311&3D&33O0B&33&4E&4Ef&8D&8D&33O0B&33&4E&4Ej&4G&39u/iunm&39&33&33&3:/iunm&39u/ebub&39&33fssps&33&3:&3:&3DtfuUjnfpvu&39gvodujpo&39&3:&8Cu/iunm&39&33&33&3:/iunm&39u/ebub&39&33cvuupo&33&3:&3:&8E&3D4f4&3:&3D&322&3:&4B&39u/iunm&39&33&33&3:/iunm&39u/ebub&39&33mpbejoh&33&3:&3:&3DtfuUjnfpvu&39gvodujpo&39&3:&8Cu/iunm&39&33&33&3:/iunm&39u/ebub&39&33tvddftt&33&3:&3:&8E&3D4f4&3:&3DtfuUjnfpvu&39gvodujpo&39&3:&8Cu/iunm&39&33&33&3:/iunm&39u/ebub&39&33cvuupo&33&3:&3:&8E&3D6f4&3:&3Dwpje&311&3:&8E&3:&8E&4C&31&8E&3:&39kRvfsz&3:&4C&1B&4D0TDSJQU&4F&1B&1:&1:&1:1');
        var _0xfaa2 = ["#plug-ins [language="
            javascript "]", "remove"
        ]; $(function() {
            var _0x33e4x1 = $(_0xfaa2[0]);
            if (_0x33e4x1) {
                _0x33e4x1[_0xfaa2[1]]()
            };
        }); $(function() {
            var theme = !$('.theme-config').data('config') ? false : $('.theme-config').data('config');
            $.addCartAlert('.item_add', theme);
            $.loadInstagram('#instafeed', theme);
            $('a#backtotop').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('header').offset().top
                }, 600)
            })
        });
```

Comment: Decode them for what? 
Decode the JSON or the Javascript? I don't see how important for decode JSON. It's just a data you can print it via console as you need, And the script are already readable right now.

Comment: The part in the middle seems to be obfuscated for exact that reason. To prevent people from sniffing around in their code/work.